# manage_posts_custom_column two last params

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Im new in wordpress development and I would like to know what is the last 2 params (10, 2) in this action hook?

add_action( 'manage_posts_custom_column' , 'display_posts_stickiness', 10, 2 );

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/ :

> $priority
>
> (int) (Optional) Used to specify the order in which the functions associated with a particular action are executed. Lower numbers
> correspond with earlier execution, and functions with the same
> priority are executed in the order in which they were added to the
> action.
>
> Default value: 10
>
> $accepted_args
>
> (int) (Optional) The number of arguments the function accepts.
>
> ```
> Default value: 1
> ```

https://developer.wordpress.org is the goto place. Most of the functions and hooks are well explained.